# grails 3.1.4 - create-app doesn't find web profile

Tags: java, grails

I've just installed grails 3.1.4 via sdkman and wanted to create a simple app. However, when typing `grails create-app testapp` I get the following error:

```
Error Profile not found for name [web]
```

I have set the necessary environment variables, e.g. GRAILS_HOME, ... I have got JDK, Apache, Tomcat installed and working.

I'm working on CentOS 6.7, 32 bit.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Grails is unable to access its artifact repositories. If you're using proxy repositories (such as internal Nexus installations), you could consider one of the following workarounds:

1. Temporarily remove the default maven user settings (~/.m2/settings.xml) if it overrides the mirror to all repositories. You could just rename it and retry your create-app command.
2. Add a proxy repository to whatever internal artifact manager software you're using (Nexus, for example, provides a proxy repository type). Point this proxy repository to resolve from the grails repo (check https://repo.grails.org/)

Remember that you will need internet access

Comment: I didn't have the file `~/.m2/settings.xml`. However, I renamed the complete folder and tried a gain and then it worked. Btw, what is Nexus for?